# Can two smooth categories be equivalent if their object manifolds aren't diffeomorphic or homotopy equivalent?

Tags: category-theory, smooth-manifolds

There is a category of "smooth categories", where the objects and the morphisms don't form sets, but manifolds (and there are some other conditions that I won't repeat here). Important examples are Lie groups and Lie groupoids such as the action groupoid of a homogeneous space.

The action groupoid of a finite $G$-set is equivalent to the stabiliser group of a point, seen as a 1-object category. I want to know whether this is the case in the smooth setting as well.

*Given two equivalent smooth categories, what can we say about their object spaces? Doesn't the equivalence imply a homotopy equivalence? Or even a diffeomorphism?*

Comment: I suppose it depends on the definition of equivalence.

Comment: @ZhenLin, what possible definitions are there, then?

Comment: There is the obvious definition involving a pair of functors. As I understand it, the correct definition should be one that generalises "fully faithful and essentially surjective on objects", sometimes called "weak equivalence". But even "essentially surjective on objects" involves a subtlety. You should ask David Roberts.

Comment: It is already not true that equivalent *categories* have isomorphic object sets (so this gives a counterexample in smooth categories where all of the manifolds are $0$-dimensional). I also don't see what the second paragraph has to do with the third.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, my motivation is to understand whether smooth action groupoids are actually equivalent to their stabiliser Lie groups (viewed as a smooth category). I was hoping that the correct notion of equivalence forbids e.g. your example, so that what you say would hopefully not be a smooth equivalence.

Comment: The only way to exclude those examples is to change the definition of category by e.g. requiring Rezk-completeness, or worse, skeletality.

Comment: @Turion: I don't see what your motivation has to do with your question.

Comment: @Qiaochu, $G//H \simeq H$ as plain categories, but I was hoping that might not be true as smooth categories because their object spaces are different.